# How to use CMake file provided by a Conan package?

Tags: cmake, conan

Bret Brown in his talk [Modern CMake Modules](https://youtu.be/IZXNsim9TWI) recommends using Conan (or other package manager) to deliver reusable CMake code.

As instructed by Brett I've created a Conan package that delivers a `MyHelpersConfig.cmake` CMake file.
(The `MyHelpersConfig.cmake` file is the *content* of the package; it is not part of the package build system.)
My Conan package delivers only this one file.

Unfortunately I don't know how to make this line in CMake actually work:

```
find_package(MyHelpers)
```

Brett mentions, that when using Conan you need to manually override `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, but he doesn't go into more detail (link to the relevant portion of his talk: [Delivering CMake modules](https://youtu.be/IZXNsim9TWI?t=3165)).

Does anyone know what needs to go into the Conan recipe, and how to use the package from CMake, to make it work?

### EDIT:

From what I was able to figure out `cmake_multi` (generator I use when consuming packages) will update `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, but only if `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set (which is rarely the case for `multi` configuration projects):

```
if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES "Debug")
    set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CONAN_CMAKE_MODULE_PATH_DEBUG} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    ...
```

We would need to add something like this to CMake (pseudocode):

```
 set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CONAN_CMAKE_MODULE_PATH_$<CONFIG>} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
```

But that is impossible.
So my conclusion would be that it should work out of the box for non-multi configuration projects, and can not possibly work for multi configuration projects.

Comment: You mentioned xxx-config.cmake, but you want find-xxx.cmake, they are different files. If you want find-xxx.cmake, you need `cmake_find_package` generator. As you commented about -config.cmake, you are using `cmake_find_package_multi`. Please, read the official documentation: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_find_package_generator.html

Comment: @uilianries Thanks for suggesting `cmake_find_package`, but the documentation for it describes a different use case: "creates a file for each requirement specified in a conanfile". I don't have any requirements.
I also don't use `cmake_find_package_multi`, and I am aware that Config files and Find files are different things. Please note that I don't want Conan to generate the Config file for me. I just want Conan to deliver the one I've prepared (this is done as described in the presentation).

Comment: Package your own cmake file is not a good option usually. It's recommended to use the generated by Conan. You can customize anything, the file name, target, etc ... But if you really want to do it, just package your cmake file as usual, you can run cmake install on package folder and copy your cmake file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was that when consuming a package from CMake Conan was not updating `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, and therefore `MyHelpersConfig.cmake` was not found.

This happened when using a `cmake_multi` generator for the consuming project.
Single-configuration generators should not have this problem, or could be solved easily by adding something like:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CONAN_CMAKE_MODULE_PATH_<BUILD-MODE-HERE>} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
```

To solve it for multi-config generators you can add the following to CMake in the consuming project:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CONAN_<YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME>_ROOT_RELEASE} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
```

This will work only under assumption that CMake files you deliver in your Conan package are the same for all build types (`Debug`, `Release`...). So it is a viable solution for general-purpose utility functions.

I don't think it is possible solve this situation when CMake files differ between build modes, simply because in multi-config projects build type is known only after all `find_package()` calls were already evaluated.

Comment: IT seems that you want to use the modern integrations, described in https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html. ``CMakeToolchain`` will define the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH for you to point to the packages folders.