# How to use an exported cmake configuration file of a required package when creating a package in Conan

Tags: cmake, conan

I'm trying to bring [VulkanSceneGraph/VSG](https://github.com/vsg-dev) to Conan and faced some challenge due to the structure that is used here.
VSG is split into multiple repositories which cover different aspects, with  being the root repository and other repositories using it as an upstream dependency.

The root-repository defines some CMake macros which are residing in the main repo .
This cmake-file is then packaged when installing vsg into the vsgConfig.cmake file.

```
find_package(Vulkan 1.1.70.0 REQUIRED)
find_dependency(Threads)

if (ANDROID)
    # TODO
elseif (WIN32)
    # just use native windowing
elseif (APPLE)
    find_library(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa)
    find_library(QUARTZCORE_LIBRARY QuartzCore)
else()
    # use Xcb for native windowing
    find_package(PkgConfig)
    pkg_check_modules(xcb REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET xcb)
endif()


include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vsgTargets.cmake")
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vsgMacros.cmake")
```

Downstream projects use the included vsgMacros.cmake in their CMakeLists.txt implicitly (they don't explicitly do `include(cmake/vsgMacros)` e.g.)

When I try to create packages for Conan, I'm struggling how to access the `vsgMacros` from the downstream Conan projects.
How can I include the vsgMacros.cmake reference into the vsgConfig.cmake generated by Conan? Or is there a better approach here?

I've already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71951640/how-to-use-cmake-file-provided-by-a-conan-package) but it seems to imply that the .cmake file is included manually.

I'd rather like to have this included into the generated vsgConfig.cmake.

Comment: I think it is worth submitting this to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues. It seems that the right solution would be to set the ``self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_build_modules")`` in the ``conanfile.py``, it would be good to share the ``conanfile.py`` there.

Comment: @drodi Thanks for the input. The whole recipe can be found [here](https://github.com/psyinf/conan-center-index/tree/vsgXchange). I worked around the issue by patching in the include into the target CMakeLists.txt. 
I'll dive into your suggestion and consider the cmake_build_modules property.