# How-to create a Conan 2.0 package that consists only of CMake source code and allows consumers to include its CMake source files?

Tags: cmake, conan

Using Conan v2.0.14 and CMake v3.27.8 I'd like to create a reusable "only-CMake-code" Conan package (`foo`) that can be consumed by another CMake project (`bar`) and allows to use the `include([...])` command in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the `bar` project in order to pull in CMake modules defined in `foo`.

I **assume** (I'm totally new to Conan, but have good knowledge of CMake) the way to go is to create a proper CMake package (either via Conan or via `CMakeLists.txt`) for `foo` that generates a `foo-config.cmake` file. This should allow `bar` to find `foo` using the `find_package(foo REQUIRED)` command. Afterwards a CMake variable defined in `foo-config.cmake` file should be accessible in `bar`, allowing the following in the `CMakeLists.txt` of `bar`:

```
include("${foo_ROOT}/foo_module.cmake")
```

My current `conanfile.py` of `foo` looks as follows:

```
from os import path
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, CMakeToolchain
from conan.tools.files import copy

required_conan_version = ">=2.0.14"

class Recipe(ConanFile):
    name = "foo"
    version = "latest"

    exports_sources = "tool/cmake/*"
    no_copy_source = True

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.generate()

    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install()

        copy(self, "tool/cmake/*", self.source_folder, self.package_folder)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.bindirs = []
        self.cpp_info.libdirs = []
```

Running `conan create` outputs the following error:

```
cmake.install()
ConanException: build_type setting should be defined.
```

I do understand the message, but now I think maybe I've chosen the wrong approach. I'd like to simply install `foo` using a CMake Package Config, but do not want to care about build configs, toolchains, etc. at all. I'm also unsure whether `foo` also requires a `CMakeLists.txt` (maybe with additional `install` commands) in order to be properly installable via Conan.

I've read the related question [How to use CMake file provided by a Conan package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71951640/891439) and its answers but it didn't help me.

Comment: There are 2 full examples in https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/graph.html that might be useful, the first 2, using a macro from a regular dependency: https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/graph/requires/consume_cmake_macro.html or from a ``tool_requires``: https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/graph/tool_requires/use_cmake_modules.html, maybe those help.

Comment: If not, probably reporting issues in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues starting from those examples could be better.

Comment: @drodri Thanks a lot! With the help of the first example I was able to create a Conan package for a CMake project and consume it via `tool_requires`. I didn't try to implement the 2nd example yet, because it requires more code (it seems each CMake module has to be explicitly listed in multiple `conanfiles.py`). Nonetheless, I'll try the 2nd approach (starting with one .cmake file that includes all other .cmake files, though this is not optimal from a performance perspective). Feel free to add an anwer and I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of examples [in the docs](https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/graph.html) that might be useful:

- using a macro from a regular dependency `requires`, [see this docs](https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/graph/requires/consume_cmake_macro.html) docs.conan.io/2/examples/graph/requires/…
- Using a macro [from a tool_requires](https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/graph/tool_requires/use_cmake_modules.html)

If the intent is to reuse some script, it might not be necessary to do a `find_package()` and make the xxx-config.cmake scripts bring the modules to use, but it is probably easier to do a plain `include(myscript)`, because the toolchains like `CMakeToolchain` will put the necessary paths in the right variables so this works (the dependency recipe has to define `self.cpp_info.builddirs` to point to the folders containing the scripts)